# FileExplorer shows only wildcard symbols in MuseScore

Tags: arch-linux, gui, i3

Since I don't have it in any other application on my ArchLinux (6.1.44-1-lts) with i3-wm it makes me wonder what is causing this behaviour?
The dialogues and fonts should be system defaults (I guess) and therefore should either work or don't in all applications using the same backend?

Does somebody have an idea what is causing it and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Wo ! Long time I've not used MuseScore. In these times, I remember that the front window was (at least in parts) some sort of web interface. Could it still be the case ?

Comment: Nope there is a standalone application now. It should use some systems dialogue - couldn't find a hint in the preferences. It is the same as the systems dialogue in Okular. Since I only have the necessary dependencies for QT/KDE to run Okular it could be that Musescore is missing some important dependency. If you have an idea which one please tell me. (Okular is working fine, the file explorer dialogue in it shows all the text and symbols just fine)

Comment: https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/media-sound/musescore/dependencies : Here you are for the list of musescore dependencies.

Comment: @MC68020 thanks but it seems that everything is present...

Comment: OK, I built 3.6.2 version from sources, It seems that under Edit > Preferences, under the General tab, Appearance section, you can select a specific Font Face that actually overrides my KDE-Plasma settings.

Comment: Such an option is not available any more in version 4.1.1-1 neither under general or its sub-categories nor under appearance (in edit->preferences). But thanks for investing so much time into helping me!!!

Comment: Anything obvious in ~/.config/MuseScore/MuseScore3Development.ini text file ? Under 3.6, was in some section labeled [ui]